# Variational Principle - Extremum is Eigenvalue

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, hilbert-space, variational-principle

Let $$A |a\rangle  = a|a\rangle.\tag{1}$$ Then the expectation value is $$\langle A\rangle_{\phi}=\frac{\langle\phi|A|\phi\rangle}{\langle \phi|\phi \rangle}.\tag{2}$$
The differential is then $$\delta \langle A\rangle_{\phi} = \frac{1}{\langle \phi|\phi \rangle} \left( \langle\delta \phi |(A-\langle A \rangle_{\phi} \mathbb{1}|\phi\rangle+\langle\phi|(A-\langle A \rangle_{\phi} \mathbb{1})|\delta \phi\rangle\right).\tag{3}$$

From this I can see that $$\delta \langle A\rangle_{\phi} =0\tag{4}$$ implies $$(A-\langle A \rangle_{\phi} \mathbb{1})|\phi\rangle = 0\tag{5}$$ and therefore it is an eigenvalue of $A$.

My problem is however how to get to the equation above. How  exactly do I have to do the differentiation?

Comment: Hint: $\delta f(|\Phi\rangle) = \left. \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\lambda} f(|\Phi\rangle + \lambda |\delta\Phi\rangle) \right|_{\lambda = 0}$.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. This was what I got wrong in the first place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First rewrite equation (3) as $$\delta \langle A \rangle_{\phi} = \frac{1}{\langle \phi |\phi\rangle} \delta \langle \phi|A|\phi \rangle-\frac{1}{\langle\phi|\phi\rangle²}\langle\phi|A|\phi\rangle \delta \langle \phi|\phi\rangle$$ where we have used the chain rule.
With the definition $\delta f(|\Phi\rangle) = \left. \frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm d\lambda} f(|\Phi\rangle + \lambda |\delta\Phi\rangle) \right|_{\lambda = 0}$ as given in the comment above we find that the second term is equal to $$\frac{d}{d \lambda} \langle\phi+\lambda\phi|\phi+\lambda \phi \rangle |_{\lambda =0}=\langle \phi + \lambda \phi |\phi \rangle + \langle \phi|\phi+\lambda\phi\rangle$$ which after setting $\lambda=0$ reduces to $=\langle\phi|\phi\rangle$.

The rest is just applying the chain rule and then putting together the terms with $\langle \delta\phi|$ and $|\delta\phi\rangle$ respectively.